# How often is a microscope used

Tags: practice-of-medicine, medical-device, test

I am planning on studying Graduate Entry into Medicine (4 years instead of 6 for people that already have a degree) in the UK.

Microscopes really irritate my eyes. I think in the UK we still have to look into the bright light, whereas in other countries they display it on a screen?

I was wondering how often I would have to use one in medical school, as a junior doctor, and which specialities would use one less often? My intention is to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: I was in a profession that extensively used microscopes ( metallurgy) ; never heard anyone complain of eye irritation . I suggest that you have a doctor examine your eyes.

Comment: I have met several people that hate microscopes. By irritate I mean it is uncomfortable and leaves your vision blurry for a while.

Comment: So much of what used to be only taught using slides has been scanned into high resolution images now, so we spend relatively little time with microscopes in the USA during medical school.  If it's not something you can get used to (like see an optometrist to see if something's wrong or fixable), then I'd avoid choosing a specialty like pathology, ophthalmology, dermatology, and ENT as those do microscopy and microscopic-procedures frequently.

Comment: @DoctorWhom I was going to pick dermatology you saved me thanks!

Comment: Of course, I would look at the actual training program you're considering before completely eliminating a specialty that interests you.  You might find the types of microscopy and devices they use are actually different from what you expected.  Compound light microscopes are not the only type of devices.  Like I said, much of the studying is done with scanned images not microscopes, depending on where you go.  And the amount of dermatopathology in dermatology differs based on program.